# UINavigationController and UITabBarController in Xcode 4

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, xcode4

I have made the switch from Xcode 3 to Xcode 4 and my whole work flow pattern is ruined. I made the change because I think iOS 5 will only be able to be developed on Xcode 4.

Anyways, making a UINavigationController with a UITabBarController used to be straight forward for me using the Interface Builder, Now I cant find the correct attributes. It feels like Apple have forgotten certain attributes from the list.

How would i do the equal of the tutorial below in xcode 4.

http://www.xcode-tutorials.com/uitabbarcontroller-and-uinavigationcontroller/

I get a different error

```
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1518) (Sat Feb 12 02:52:12 UTC 2011)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".Attaching to process 56741.
2011-06-19 15:58:31.814 FaceDirectory[56741:207] Reachability Flag Status: -R ------- networkStatusForFlags
2011-06-19 15:58:31.815 FaceDirectory[56741:207] Reachable WiFi
2011-06-19 15:58:32.792 FaceDirectory[56741:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "FaceUsersViewController" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00e315a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00f85313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00de9ef8 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00de9e6a +[NSException raise:format:] + 58
    4   UIKit                               0x0028ce9b -[UITableViewController loadView] + 275
    5   UIKit                               0x0013300e -[UIViewController view] + 56
    6   UIKit                               0x00131482 -[UIViewController contentScrollView] + 42
    7   UIKit                               0x00141f25 -[UINavigationController _computeAndApplyScrollContentInsetDeltaForViewController:] + 48
    8   UIKit                               0x00140555 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 43
    9   UIKit                               0x00141870 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 524
    10  UIKit                               0x0013c32a -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded] + 266
    11  UIKit                               0x002572e9 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 226
    12  QuartzCore                          0x01952a5a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 181
    13  QuartzCore                          0x01954ddc CALayerLayoutIfNeeded + 220
    14  QuartzCore                          0x018fa0b4 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 310
    15  QuartzCore                          0x018fb294 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 292
    16  QuartzCore                          0x018fb46d _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 99
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00e1289b __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 27
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00da76e7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 295
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00d701d7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1575
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00d6f840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x00d6f761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x013091c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x01309289 GSEventRun + 115
    24  UIKit                               0x00091c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    25  FaceDirectory                       0x00002689 main + 121
    26  FaceDirectory                       0x00002605 start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about changing `FirstViewController` from a View Controller to a Navigation Controller - then edit `FirstViewController` so that the declaration looks like this:

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {
```

I also see that the views and their controllers have already been created and hooked up for you.

**Edit**

The edited question shows that you haven't set up the view outlet for `FacetimeUsersViewController` nib

Comment: check the updated error please. I have a tableView on the FaceUsersViewController

Comment: Now you have a `UITableViewController` loading a view that isn't a `UITableView`. It says so in the error message.

Comment: it is a UITableView tho, thats what I dont understand :S

Comment: I can't guess what's going on unless I see how you've set things up, though.

Comment: i have three xib files, one is the MainWindow, which has a tab bar on it, one tab is a basic view controller, the other is a UInavigationcontroller. within the UINavigationController, the view controller is set to FaceUsersViewController. The FaceUsersViewController has a tableView on it with its delegate and data source set to the file owner which is set to FaceUsersViewController class.

Comment: Is FaceUsersViewController a subclass of UIViewController or UITableViewController?

Comment: subclass of UITableViewController